# Formula for finding the value in a range of cells that is closest to zero, where those cells include letters

Tags: google-sheets

I want cell A4 to show the number in cells A1:A3 that is closest to zero, including if that number is negative, and where some of those cells may contain "na".
I've tried MIN with ABS but that can't handle the "na".
many thanks in advance.
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(min(iferror(abs(A1:A3))))
```

If you wanted to find the original value with its sign (+/-), would need something like

```
=ArrayFormula(index(A1:A3,match(min(iferror(abs(A1:A3))),iferror(abs(A1:A3)),0)))
```

Comment: You're welcome! Will add to the answer another formula in case you need to find the original value with its sign.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=min(ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(A1:A3),abs(A1:A3))))
```